# How to say "Received payments" in one word

Tags: word-choice, american-english, british-english

I want to say "Received payments" meaning the payments that have been confirmed and received by us, but i want to say this in one word, because its a table name and i'd like to use one word to describe it if possible, does such a word exists?
Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as Off Topic because our Help Center specifically rules questions about naming things in programming to lie outside of our site's scope. Plus you should use `multi_word_identifiers` not `uniwords`. :)

Answer (score 1):

You could call them *remittances*:

> **remittance** noun
>
> [ C ] an amount of money that you send to someone:
>
> *She sends a small remittance home to her parents each month.*
>   ​
>   [ U ] the act of sending payment to someone:
>
> *remittance advice/information*

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/remittance)

Comment: What do you think about "Paid", do you think this will work as well ?, please think of this words as a title for a table